# Parameter value [0%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)];

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Spring and JPA to make queries to a database, but I have a problem when using the LIKE operator together with LocalDate, Long and BigDecimal, since my goal is to know if it matches the one passed by parameter, and if not, I would like to have an empty date by default (I tried with LocalDate.parse("") but apparently that is not the way), an empty BigDecimal and an empty Long. Here is the repository:

```
    @Query(value = 
                    "SELECT pe.nombre AS nombre, pe.apellido AS apellido, pe.dni AS dni, pe.pais AS pais, pe.direccion AS direccion, pe.telefono AS telefono, pe.mail AS mail, pg.producto AS producto, pg.fechaPago as fecha, tp.nombre as tipoPago, pg.comprobante AS comprobante, pg.monto AS monto " +
                    "FROM Persona pe JOIN FETCH Pago pg ON pe=pg.persona JOIN FETCH TipoPago tp ON tp=pg.tipo " +
                    "WHERE pe.nombre LIKE :nombrePersona% " +
                    "AND pe.apellido LIKE :apellidoPersona% " +
                    "AND pe.dni LIKE :dni% " +
                    "AND pe.pais LIKE :pais% " +
                    "AND pe.direccion LIKE :direccion% " +
                    "AND pe.telefono LIKE :telefono% " +
                    "AND pe.mail LIKE :mail% " +
                    "AND pg.producto LIKE :producto% " +
                    "AND tp.nombre LIKE :tipoPago% " +
                    "AND pg.comprobante LIKE :comprobante% " +
                    "AND pg.monto LIKE :monto% " +
                    "AND (pg.fechaPago LIKE :fechaPago%) "
            )
            List<PersonaPagoDTO> filtrarPersonaPago(
                    @Param("nombrePersona") String nombrePersona,
                            @Param("apellidoPersona") String apellidoPersona, 
                            @Param("dni") String dni,
                            @Param("pais") String pais, 
                            @Param("direccion") String direccion,
                            @Param("telefono") Long telefono, 
                            @Param("mail") String mail,
                            @Param("producto") String producto, 
                            @Param("fechaPago") LocalDate fechaPago,
                            @Param("tipoPago") String tipoPago, 
                            @Param("comprobante") String comprobante,
                            @Param("monto") BigDecimal monto
            );
```

The resource:

```
    @GetMapping("/personas/filtrar/pago")
        public List<PersonaPagoDTO> filtrarPersonaPago(
            PersonaPagoParams personaPagoParams
        ) {
            return personaRepository.filtrarPersonaPago(personaPagoParams.getNombrePersona(), personaPagoParams.getApellidoPersona(), personaPagoParams.getDni(), personaPagoParams.getPais(), personaPagoParams.getDireccion(), personaPagoParams.getTelefono(), personaPagoParams.getMail(), personaPagoParams.getProducto(), personaPagoParams.getFechaPago(), personaPagoParams.getTipoPago(), personaPagoParams.getComprobante(), personaPagoParams.getMonto());
        }
```

And the class with the parameters

```
public class PersonaPagoParams {

    private String nombrePersona = "";
    private String apellidoPersona = "";
    private String dni = "";
    private String pais = "";
    private String direccion = "";
    private Long telefono = 0L;
    private String mail = "";
    private String producto = "";
    private LocalDate fechaPago = LocalDate.parse("");
    private String tipoPago = "";
    private String comprobante = "";
    private BigDecimal monto = BigDecimal.ZERO;
// Getters and setters
```

Comment: You should convert those fields to text in your query if you want to do a textual comparison. `LIKE` means nothing in a numerical context.

Comment: Perfect, I think I understand. So I should enclose these values in single quotes? For example:
LIKE ':fechaPago%'

Comment: No, you should do something like `AND cast(pg.monto as text) LIKE :monto% `. And the `monto` parameter to the method should probably be a string as well.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much Federico!

Comment: What do you think the `%` after the parameter name does? Did you maybe mean `LIKE :monto || '%'` (or `LIKE CONCAT(:monto, '%')`?

Comment: I mean LIKE CONCAT(:monto, '%').
For example url?monto=500
So...
```monto LIKE '500%';```